# Get email by its messageId from microsoft graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to get a mail message from Microsoft Graph just by its id without UserId / Mailbox name?

I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http but it seems to need a user reference in all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No to get Messages you need to use one of the Messages Endpoints which are either in the /Me context of /Users contact. If all you have is the Id and you want to work out which mailbox it came from then the Id does contain the MailboxGuid